# How do I get an object to move and swap places with another object, on a mouse clic

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, transform, swap, gameobject

I have a script so far that moves an object a small distance upon a mouse click, however I want to change it so that when I click this object, it swaps places with another obejct next to it, instead of just the small distance it is moving now. I am a little confused on how to do this, because I am new to unity.

```
 using UnityEngine;
 using System.Collections;

 public class NewBehaviourScript: MonoBehaviour
 {
     public float movementSpeed = 10;

     void Update(){
         if ( Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
         {
             transform.Translate(Vector3.right * movementSpeed * Time.deltaTime);
         }


     }
 }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

```
 using UnityEngine;
 using System.Collections;

 public class NewBehaviourScript: MonoBehaviour {
     public GameObject objectA; //Needs to be initialized in the editor, or on Start
     public GameObject objectB; //Needs to be initialized in the editor, or on Start
     public float movementSpeed = 10;
     private Vector3 posA = Vector3.zero; //Vector3.zero is for initialization
     private Vector3 posB = Vector3.zero; //Vector3.zero is for initialization

     void Update() {
         if ( Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0)) {
             posA = objectA.gameObject.transform.position;
             posB = objectB.gameObject.transform.position;
             objectA.gameObject.transform.position = posB;
             objectB.gameObject.transform.position = posA;
         }
     }

 }
```

This just saves each objects position into the posA and posB variables, then you move objectA to posB and objectB to posA.

-OR-

Now if objectB is always a different object (NOT constant) and you aren't sure how to find the nearest object, you could use a raycast. Add the following function to your code:

```
gamObject NearestObject () {
    int dist;
    int nearestIndex;
    //Create an array to contain objects to be hit by the raycast
    RaycastHit[] nearby;
    //Hit all objects within 100 units with a raycast, change the 100 as needed
    nearby = Physics.RaycastAll(objectA.transform.position, transform.forward, 100.0f);
    //Check if there is at least one object
    if(nearby.Length > 0) {
        //If there is only one object and it's not objectA
        if(!(nearby.Length == 1 && nearby[0].transform == objectA.transform)) {
            dist = nearby[0].distance;
            nearestIndex = 0;
            for (int i = 1; i < nearby.Length; i++) {
                if(nearby[i].transform != gameObject.transform && nearby[i].distance < dist)
                    dist = nearby[i].distance;
                    nearestIndex = i;
                }
            }
        } else {
           //There is only one object in the raycast and it is objectA
           nearestIndex = -1; 
        }
    } else {
        //There are no objects nearby
        nearestIndex = -1;
    }
    //nearestIndex will only be negative one if there are no objects near objectA, so return null
    if (nearestIndex == -1) {
        return null;
    } else {
        //return nearest object to update
        return nearby[nearestIndex].gameObject;
    }
}
```

Finally, change Update to:

```
     void Update() {
         if ( Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0)) {
             objectB = NearestObject ();
             if (objectB != null) {
                 posA = objectA.gameObject.transform.position;
                 posB = objectB.gameObject.transform.position;
                 objectA.gameObject.transform.position = posB;
                 objectB.gameObject.transform.position = posA;
             }
         }
     }
```

Answer (score 3):

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class NewBehaviourScript : MonoBehaviour
{
    //making them public just to be able watch values change in game mode
    public float movementSpeed = 10;
    public GameObject g1;
    public GameObject g2;
    public Vector3 vec1;
    public Vector3 vec2 = new Vector3(2F, 2F, 2F);
    public bool swapBack = false;

    void Start()
    {
        g1 = GameObject.Find("Cube");
        g2 = GameObject.Find("Sphere");
        vec1 = new Vector3(g1.gameObject.transform.position.x, g1.gameObject.transform.position.y, g1.gameObject.transform.position.z);
        vec2 = new Vector3(g2.gameObject.transform.position.x, g2.gameObject.transform.position.y, g2.gameObject.transform.position.z);
    }

    void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
        {
            transform.Translate(Vector3.right * movementSpeed * Time.deltaTime);
            swap(swapBack);
        }
    }

    public void swap(bool back)
    {
        if (back)
        {
            g1.transform.position = vec1;
            g2.transform.position = vec2;
            swapBack = false;
        }
        else
        {
            g1.transform.position = vec2;
            g2.transform.position = vec1;
            swapBack = true;
        }
    }
}
```